# To set Google Map in my web page

Tags: jsapi

I want to set a Google map in my web page. Can any one guide me what I have to do ? From where I have to start? I am getting some wrong values of latitude and longitude when I am trying with the google api please suggest mw how i have to start this and what was the exact way we have to follow for this google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basics of everything you need:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: ok I will use it and then what we have to do can explain briefly

Comment: the code is direct html so if you just plug it into your website the code should work.Place it in <div> holders or whatever you want for style formatting.I'm not sure what you want to do but you can read it for further information.The basics are all there of how to show a basic map and place point markers etc.

If you want latitude and longitude, then you might have to do geocoding etc.